# How can i add a function to show me history of calculations and results?

Tags: python

How can i add a function to show me history of calculations and results? Either in the console or create a .txt file. This is code I got from the internet BTW. I am a beginner to python also.

## Program make a simple calculator

```
# This function adds two numbers
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

# This function subtracts two numbers
def subtract(x, y):
    return x - y

# This function multiplies two numbers
def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

# This function divides two numbers
def divide(x, y):
    return x / y


print("Select operation.")
print("1.Add")
print("2.Subtract")
print("3.Multiply")
print("4.Divide")

while True:
    # take input from the user
    choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4): ")

    # check if choice is one of the four options
    if choice in ('1', '2', '3', '4'):
        num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))

        if choice == '1':
            print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add(num1, num2))

        elif choice == '2':
            print(num1, "-", num2, "=", subtract(num1, num2))

        elif choice == '3':
            print(num1, "*", num2, "=", multiply(num1, num2))

        elif choice == '4':
            print(num1, "/", num2, "=", divide(num1, num2))
        
        # check if user wants another calculation
        # break the while loop if answer is no
        next_calculation = input("Let's do next calculation? (yes/no): ")
        if next_calculation == "no":
          break
    
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modification of your text to write to a file (e.g. 'log.txt')

- Opens file in append mode
- Using Python [string interpolation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/) to compose string to write

**Code**

```
# This function adds two numbers
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

# This function subtracts two numbers
def subtract(x, y):
    return x - y

# This function multiplies two numbers
def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

# This function divides two numbers
def divide(x, y):
    return x / y


print("Select operation.")
print("1.Add")
print("2.Subtract")
print("3.Multiply")
print("4.Divide")

with open('log.txt', 'a') as history: # open file 'log.txt' in append mode for logging
    while True:
        # take input from the user
        choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4): ")

        # check if choice is one of the four options
        if choice in ('1', '2', '3', '4'):
            num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
            num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))

            if choice == '1':
                print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add(num1, num2))
                history.write(f'{num1} + {num2} = {add(num1, num2)}\n') # append to history file

            elif choice == '2':
                print(num1, "-", num2, "=", subtract(num1, num2))
                history.write(f'{num1} - {num2} = {subtract(num1, num2)}\n') # append to history file

            elif choice == '3':
                print(num1, "*", num2, "=", multiply(num1, num2))
                history.write(f'{num1} * {num2} = {multiply(num1, num2)}\n') # append to history file

            elif choice == '4':
                print(num1, "/", num2, "=", divide(num1, num2))
                history.write(f'{num1} / {num2} = {divide(num1, num2)}\n') # append to history file

            # check if user wants another calculation
            # break the while loop if answer is no
            next_calculation = input("Let's do next calculation? (yes/no): ")
            if next_calculation == "no":
              break

        else:
            print("Invalid Input")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a `print` statement inside each of your functions.
i.e:

```
def add(x, y):
    result = x + y
    print('add', x, y, 'result =', result)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
# This function adds two numbers
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

# This function subtracts two numbers
def subtract(x, y):
    return x - y

# This function multiplies two numbers
def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

# This function divides two numbers
def divide(x, y):
    return x / y


print("Select operation.")
print("1.Add")
print("2.Subtract")
print("3.Multiply")
print("4.Divide")
print("5.History")

history = []

while True:
    # take input from the user
    choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4/5): ")

    # check if choice is one of the four options
    if choice in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'):
        num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))

        if choice == '1':
            result = add(num1, num2)
            history.append(f'{num1} + {num2} = {result}')
            print(history[-1])

        elif choice == '2':
            result = subtract(num1, num2)
            history.append(f'{num1} - {num2} = {result}')
            print(history[-1])

        elif choice == '3':
            result = multiply(num1, num2)
            history.append(f'{num1} * {num2} = {result}')
            print(history[-1])

        elif choice == '4':
            result = divide(num1, num2)
            history.append(f'{num1} / {num2} = {result}')
            print(history[-1])
        elif choice == '5':
            print(*history, sep='\n')
        
        # check if user wants another calculation
        # break the while loop if answer is no
        next_calculation = input("Let's do next calculation? (yes/no): ")
        if next_calculation == "no":
          break
    
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
```

Basically you keep a list with all previous printed messages, and you print them all whenever the user chooses option '5'.

Answer (score 0):

One really neat way to do it is with [decorators](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/). With this approach you only have to write the logic once and can apply it to all the functions. This logic is specific for binary operations but could obviously be extended and also modified to write to a log file:

```
# `log_op` is the decorator
def log_op(f_name, f_op):
  def wrapper(f):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
      result = f(*args, **kwargs)
      print(f"{f_name}: {args[0]} {f_op} {args[1]} = {result}")
      return result
    return inner
  return wrapper

@log_op('add', '+')
def add(x, y):
  return x + y
  
@log_op('subtract', '-')
def subtract(x, y):
  return x - y
  
add(1,2) # add: 1 + 2 = 3
subtract(1,2) # subtract: 1 - 2 = -1
```